# When set ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to IntegerSerializer in ProducerConfigs in Spring boot kafka, it gives class cast exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I m using this [Spring boot with kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#with-java-configuration)
to setup my project. but when i run it it will give `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert key of class java.lang.Integer to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in key.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`
this exception when send the request using kafka template.

```
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1)
@SpringBootTest
class KafkaApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyKafkaListener listener;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> template;

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

    @Test
    public void testSimple() throws Exception {
        template.send("annotated1", 0, "foo");
        template.flush();
        assertTrue(this.listener.latch1.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableKafka
    public class Config {

        @Bean
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String>
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                    new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
        }

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
//          props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        }

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
//          props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
            props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<Integer, String>(producerFactory());
        }

    }
}
```

But when I change that `template.send("annotated1", "key-foo", "foo");` it will work. I have used

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    return props;
}
```

this configuration as well. But it is still giving me the 
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String**

If someone there please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the main application class and Config class to the `@SpringBootTest`

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { So61985794Application.class, So61985794ApplicationTests.Config.class })
```

to override Boot's normal configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have figured out what I have missed.

`@Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<Integer, String>(producerFactory());
        }`

So in here my Key is Integer and value is String for the producer factory. But I have set

`props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);`

So I have changed that one to **StringSerializer.class** and I have removed 0 from this code and it worked.

Comment: But I have one concern. When I changed the 0 integer to "0" (String zero), it worked. Can you explain why is that ? I know by default **ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG** and **ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG** are using **StringSerializer.class**